# Is there any R function to combine different csv after removing certain number of rows?

Tags: csv, merge, naming

I have 270 csv files with names given as 1_column_1_20230605_101518_r.csv, 2_column_1_20230605_101521_r.csv. There are x number of rows whose information is not useful so I want to remove the X rows and then combine 270 csvs into a single csv. I have two columns in each csv with one column common in all csvs. Also, in the new combined csv I want to add a column for each file name such as 1 for 1_column_1_20230605_101518_r.csv, 2 for 2_column_1_20230605_101521_r.csv and so on. Please help.